# On the use of multiple accounts to pre-emptively get around a question ban

Tags: discussion, post-ban, sock-puppets, duplicate-accounts

There's this one guy I've seen around Stack Overflow the past week or two, posting the normal "I'm stuck on my homework, please help me" questions. However, he seems to be doing it in a fairly interesting way, using a new account for each question, and I suspect his motives for the multiple accounts aren't "pure". Here is the most recent "series" of questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498459/how-to-return-different-size-array
- [How to crop out given points in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496691/how-to-crop-out-given-points-in-java)
- [croping an array list in java [rectangle]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482004/croping-an-array-list-in-java-rectangle)
- [Croping out points from an array list in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443659/croping-out-points-from-an-array-list-in-java)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460886/croping-points-in-an-arraylist-in-java (deleted, also duplicate of above)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440072/return-an-array-of-two-points-that-are-closets-together (deleted)

Previous questions include, but are not limited to:

- [Setting up a toString() method for an array list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421820/setting-up-a-tostring-method-for-an-array-list)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316262/shuffling-two-arrays (deleted)

Now, earlier I flagged his questions because his main account was suspended for vandalizing the shuffling question, and he wanted to keep posting using alt accounts despite the suspension.

However, when the suspension lifted, he kept going with this rather odd behavior. And now I'm wondering whether this is to avoid question bans before they even happen, perhaps because he was burned by one on one of his previous accounts. Judging by the most recent questions, if he hadn't kept creating new accounts, he almost certainly would have received a ban.

I have to admit I'm biased. I'm not really a fan of his questions, nor of his behavior. His questions, to me, are usually vague, poorly-formatted, don't deal with a specific problem, are almost always of the broad "I'm stuck, can anyone give me any pointers" variety, don't show any research effort or things he has tried, and in at least one case the question's scope ballooned into a debugging fest because he didn't give enough information at the beginning as to what exactly was wrong. It's also frustrating to watch his questions get answered anyways, as it basically means his program is written for him bit by bit without any evidence of effort on his side. To be honest, I'm surprised his questions didn't gather more downvotes/close votes than they did.

In addition, I don't have access to the history of his questions, so I can't confirm for myself whether his questions in general have been low-scoring enough to earn a question ban, or if it's just a recent thing. I think the quality issue has always been there; I'm just not sure whether the downvotes were also there.

Am I justified in thinking that this is suspicious/inappropriate behavior? Or am I just seeing things through tinted glasses and/or totally off my rocker and this is OK? If this is actually inappropriate behavior, can anything be done about it? *Should* anything be done about it?

If any clarification is needed, please ask.

Comment: "If any clarification is needed, please ask. I wrote this in a hurry, and I'm not sure whether I included everything needed or if I am typing coherently."  I realize this is metaSO, not SO, but isn't that the pot calling the kettle black?

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser Huh?

Comment: How is "I wrote this in a hurry, and I'm not sure whether I included everything needed or if I am typing coherently" substantially different than what the subject of this question is doing?

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser ...Sorry, I don't get it... In any case, it's not relevant to the rest of the question, so I'll remove it.

Comment: Maybe if someone would just tell him how to do croping, whatever that is, he'd go away. Oh, I just noticed how old this Q is. Maybe he's already gone.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes it is inappropriate behaviour and if you think you've found someone doing this just flag one of their posts with the "other" option giving you evidence. We'll take a look and take the appropriate action.

There's no need to publicly name them here on meta.

Comment: All right, I suppose I'll do that then. I just wasn't sure as to whether the pre-emptive part made things different and/or if I was biased against this user, but I suppose not. I suppose this question should be deleted then?

Comment: @user3580294 - perhaps just edit out the account details. It might be useful to have a question like this for future reference.