# Tags [sock-puppets] and [duplicate-accounts] have the same meaning

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request, meta

I recently came across the tags [sock-puppets](/questions/tagged/sock-puppets) and [duplicate-accounts](/questions/tagged/duplicate-accounts) in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262060/on-the-use-of-multiple-accounts-to-pre-emptively-get-around-a-question-ban), but they however mean the same thing:

> *Duplicate accounts which are all owned by the same person, usually to escape post-bans.*

Can they be merged, since it's no use having two different tags, meaning exactly the same thing.
I'll suggest that [sock-puppets](/questions/tagged/sock-puppets) is merged into [duplicate-accounts](/questions/tagged/duplicate-accounts), since it will be easier for users to identify using the [duplicate-accounts](/questions/tagged/duplicate-accounts) tag as opposed to [sock-puppets](/questions/tagged/sock-puppets).

Comment: [tag:duplicate-accounts] has one post in it, the one you linked. [tag:sock-puppets] has only three posts in it...

Comment: @dav_i True, but wouldn't is be best to merge them, to prevent any confusion over future questions?

Comment: Duplicate accounts do not necessarily include sock puppets. Duplicate accounts can be created accidentally, sock puppets suggests an intent to bypass the rules by using duplicate accounts.

Comment: @MartijnPieters True.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, a duplicate account does *not* automatically mean the extra account was created on purpose. A sock-puppet on the other hand is a duplicate account created on purpose, possibly for nefarious purposes.

People that want help with merging accidental extra accounts should not have to be called sock-puppets.

I've updated the tag wikis for both tags to clarify their meaning a little.