# Does reviewing count as "positive contributions"?

Tags: support, review-queues, post-ban

I am stuck with a question ban which makes it really hard for me to use the site. I don't quite understand what I did wrong in my questions and the help page that gets linked isn't helpful at all imho. But I digress.

It did mention something about being unbanned when positive contributions outweight the negative, does reviewing count as positive? Meaning if I review enough it will get me unblocked from asking.

Right now I am stuck in a disgusting situation in which I am pretty much forced to create throw-away accounts in order to ask questions.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get a lot of sympathy by admitting you're [creating multiple accounts in an attempt to get around the question ban](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262060/on-the-use-of-multiple-accounts-to-pre-emptively-get-around-a-question-ban).

Comment: You know you *can* ask questions about how to improve your questions here. You can also ask questions on meta if you can't find information on pretty well anything to do with Stack Overflow. Creating throw away accounts because "help page that gets linked isn't helpful at all" shows an inherent lack of research effort.

Comment: Don't you think it is important that you can review your own posts first??

Comment: @Hans Passant: They would be biased, though.

Comment: @BSMP Ah well that's the thing. I am pretty much forced to do that. You say this as if I want it to be like this which is simply not the case.

Comment: You're not "forced" to do _anything_, much less commit the offence of ban evasion.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Situation: I want to ask questions but can't do so on account. Solution: ???. That was the only one I figured out.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev: The keyword there is "want". Posting questions on Stack Overflow to receive free help is not a right; it's a privilege, and you've eschewed it for the duration of your ban.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What you are saying is a bit irrelevant in the context of websites. You can say the same about using Twitter, that "tweeting" is a privilege and not a right. And that would be true. But they are still free platforms in a way. Anybody can ask questions and get answers.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev The solution is to **improve your posts**, read [help] & [ask], and **stop using multiple accounts to get around your question ban**. Once you've done that, you'll find that your questions are better received by the community, and as such you'll be much happier with the result.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev: Not if they've been banned, they can't. That's not "irrelevant" whatsoever.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev Lightness is correct: literally *anything* you have access to on Stack Exchange sites is a right that you earn, it's not something you're entitled to. That's why the reputation system exists; with higher reputation you're more trusted, and earn the right to do more stuff on the site.

Comment: You are not forced to commit ban evasion.  You can fix your existing questions.  You can not ask questions.  You can provide solid answers.  All are options.  You may not like those options, but that does not mean ban evasion is "forced" on you.  I understand, it is like there is a chocolate bar on a store shelf and you have no money, but you want that chocolate bar, so you are "forced" to steal it.  And when caught shoplifting, and they ban you from the store, you are "forced" to get a baseball bat, break the glass, and steal it that way.  Anything that blocks your desires is clearly wrong.

Comment: Ban evasion is not a criminal offence.

Comment: @MartinSmith - The community has been [pretty clear](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262060/on-the-use-of-multiple-accounts-to-pre-emptively-get-around-a-question-ban) that using [multiple accounts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260430/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-a-user-with-multiple-accounts-and-what-action-will/260434#260434) to [get around bans](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126746/293308) is against the rules.

Comment: @BSMP using terms like "commit the offence" and drawing parallels with shop lifting is ridiculous though.

Answer (score 26):

No, at this time reviewing other people's contributions doesn't count towards unlocking the ability to post if you ended up with a ban.

I can see arguments both ways on that, but ultimately what we're looking for from someone with a question or answer ban is positive *content* contributions, e.g. things that may be *vetted by other users* through voting or reviewing.

> I am pretty much forced to create throw-away accounts in order to ask questions

I'm sorry if this comes off the wrong way (and I haven't looked up your other accounts or even the one you're posting this from), but have you considered the possibility that you're asking the wrong questions and/or asking the right questions badly? Getting blocked from asking is supposed to tell you something. You can ignore the message and create "throw-away accounts", or you can learn and improve. It's up to you.