# Don't allow post banned users to review posts

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, post-ban

If a user has demonstrated that their contributions are so problematic that we feel that it's necessary to prohibit them from asking and/or answering questions, they shouldn't be allowed to review the contributions of others using the /review page.

To be able to effectively use the review tool one needs to have a strong understanding of the rules and culture of the site and be able to recognize problematic content (and ideally how to fix it). To get post banned, a user has demonstrated that they *don't* know how to recognize content that doesn't belong on the site, given that they've posted a lot of it, and they've demonstrated an inability to fix it.

Comment: I'm concerned about this...it's not that I disagree *in principle*, but I wonder how many users in practice this applies to.

Comment: @Makoto [At least some](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313559/does-reviewing-count-as-positive-contributions).  (Hence why I posted this in the first place.)  I can certainly see how, if you're not allowed to ask/answer, and are just looking for possible ways to interact with the site (as per the instructions in the help center on the post ban) you'd find /review.  It does make some sense.  And of course, putting this in place would be pretty simple, so the cost shouldn't be too high.

Comment: Again, it's not that I disagree - I do feel that *some* sort of restriction on reviews should be placed by those who are post banned - I'm just not sure what kind of precedent this sets.  It isn't as if *everyone* that is post banned is utter scum and doesn't deserve to interact with the site, in spite of how rare that case is.

Comment: Isn't there a deeper problem? Isn't this (yet another) sign that low quality stuff  gets up voted, despite being a low quality contributor?

Comment: @Makoto Setting the precedent that a user that has provided *significant* negative contributions, few to no positive contributions, and an inability to improve their problematic content or to learn from it needs to take the time to address the problems with their own content, or prove that they've learned from their mistakes and are now able to post positive contributions, before they're qualified to judge the quality of the contributions of others (or to help them improve the quality of others' contributions) seems like a precedence that I'm *entirely* satisfied with.

Comment: @rene I don't 'know that this is a symptom/sign of that.  I do think that's a problem, but when low quality content gets upvoted *people don't get post banned*, so this isn't exactly a symptom/sign of that particular problem.

Comment: Given that review requires [500 reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) and most question-banned users have considerably less [citation needed], I'm not sure this would impact very many people at all. (I'm assuming the review ban would be cleared when the post ban is.) If so, this would be a very marginal change; I'd be surprised if it produced any noticeable change for anyone but the banned users themselves.

Comment: "Inability to improve" is the key word here.  I maintain that I don't disagree in principle, but in practice I've heard of *very few* people actually accomplishing the feat of cleaning up their old posts and getting unbanned, partly due to the stereotype that heavily downvoted content is bad and should be downvoted *further*.  It kind of feels like we're kicking them when they're down, honestly.  Again, it's not that I disagree, but the ability to escape from purgatory isn't all that common.

Comment: @JonEricson I hadn't looked at that recently.  I believe it used to be lower, but has since been increased.  Are triage and the HI queue also 500, or are they lower?

Comment: @Makoto I've seen it happen a few times.  In the vast majority of cases, people don't even try (Shog's data has a pretty small percentage of review banned users ever editing their posts after getting banned, but I don't remember where it was posted.)  It's not that a lot of people spend a lot of time and effort improving their posts and then stay banned.

Comment: @Servy: H&I is 2k; Triage has never been anything but 500; FP/LA haven't been less than 500 for well over a year at the very least.

Comment: you will basically force users that have fallen into a suspended trap, even if that had valueable knowledge before to just leave this site. Since there is no way out for them, you also encourage DDOS, and encourage spam accounts when you limit what a user can do when they tried everything to get out that hole. That will lead to increased costs to this site and alienate a lot of people. lets just hope u understand what you are asking is out anger not logic.

Answer (score 18):

If true, this is a bug, plain and simple.

- Being able to ask question and post answers requires a very low level of privilege; even anonymous newcomers to the site can ask a question.
- Being able to review the contributions of others requires significant privilege.
- Having a low privilege removed, while being allowed to exercise the permissions of a high privilege is a "privilege inversion"; which can be regarded as a security flaw.

At least, if we accept a simple, one-dimensional concept of privilege. Which we do here. Stack Exchange sites do operate on such a concept. Users have a single point count, increasing values of which increase privilege. If you can lose all privilege, yet retain certain high-privilege capabilities, it destroys the meaning of that scale.

If different capabilities are governed by separate permission variables, then the issue is moot. That is to say, if there is a separate permission "bit" to ask a question, to post an answer, to review and so forth, then there is no "banning": only the removal of specific permissions, and we can talk about whether it ever makes "administrative sense" to revoke someone's question-asking permission while retaining their review permission. (Opinion: it's hard to see when it ever would.)