# Is it fair to close a question based on off-site interactions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-closed, code-of-conduct

**Background**:

For over a year, I was a member of the Julia Discourse site. After some time my relationship with the forum deteriorated and I decided to leave, in not the best way. I was verbally abusive with the community and requested my account be deleted.

I was going over some material and needed to ask [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69598304/discrepancy-about-when-to-use-type-annotations), so I decided to post it on Stack Overflow. The cocreator of the language found my question and said he would vote to close my question because of what happened on Discourse.

My question is in fact valid and on-topic for Stack Overflow.

1. Is it appropriate to downvote/close-vote a question based on what happened on another forum?
2. Would it be possible to reopen the question?

If Stack Overflow determines the question is in fact **not on-topic** or **not a good fit**, then I'll accept it.

Comment: They can downvote it, if they wish so. What they are not allowed to do is serial voting or using sockpuppets to also vote. So you should only have to fear one downvote. Three close votes are necessary to close a question (in your case it's not closed as duplicate), so they alone cannot close it, they need 2 more users who think it's not suitable for SO.

Comment: I really don't see how that is a valid close reason *for the question*. The question content seems not related to the feud at all.

Comment: On SO we should try to judge the content, not the user. So your behavior on that other website should not matter when deciding on which action to take with regards to your question.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - The question is considered on-topic for SO, correct?

Comment: @EmpressSvetlana Let me put it this way: Whether [a question is on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) depends *only* on the content of the question. The identity of the author is irrelevant for that.

Comment: I was the one that cast the first Reopen vote, and (since all comments there have been deleted) these are the other Meta questions I cited in explaining the vote: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226499/131904 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340093/131904

Comment: @StefanKarpinski No, we're not going to rehash the details of what happened on another site/forum over here. I've rolled back your edit attempting to add more of that history. Please read the answer below, which mentions that explicitly.

Comment: @IanCampbell See revision 11. It's not a grammatical mistake.

Comment: "My question is in fact valid and on-topic for Stack Overflow." This is not a fact unless the community think it is. I don't use Julia and wouldn't dream of judging your specific question, but I see versions of this fallacy frequently. "My question is clear, so why was it closed as unclear?" "My question is on-topic, so why..."

Comment: @cigien I *do* think the history is relevant here, actually. It's pertinent that this was a repost of a question recently asked on the other forum, that the suspension on that forum was for unambiguously bad behaviour (namely posting porn) rather than just some unfortunate clash of personalities, and that the latest suspension was only a few days ago. The closure here was still not proper even so, but pre-emptively nuking a cross-site duplicate posted by someone who moments ago was trolling your community with porn is quite different to acting on an old grudge over unrelated past misbehaviour.

Comment: @MarkAmery Sorry, in how far is that relevant or the actions *substantially* different? None of what you have cited seems to make a question off-topic. The history seems not to change the answer to this meta-question one bit.

Comment: @MarkAmery I'm not sure what I can add to Cody's answer below, but let me be as explicit as possible. We do *not* care what happens off-site. Period. We are certainly not going to litigate who was right, or wrong, in that scenario. One's behavior on SO, or any SE site, is certainly relevant, but this is not one of those cases (I mention this specifically since you used "cross-site duplicate" which typically means "on a different SE site"). Users are judged solely by their behavior on SE, not how they've behaved elsewhere.

Comment: @NickCox - I was confident enough to say it's on topic because questions about types and how to use them have already been asked for different languages. For example, Python alone, you can find posts explaining the correct usage of type hints (which I think my question is about, only for Julia).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi it's relevant because it makes it reasonable to foresee *exactly the same sequence of events* playing out here, and so makes the actions look more like a good-faith attempt to defend Stack Overflow and less like a petty retaliation for past wrongs. The question "can I use related off-site conduct as evidence that someone's actions here are actually abusive and that if we engage with their question we'll get porn-spammed" is different to "can I retaliate against good-faith Stack Overflow questions to punish entirely irrelevant off-site conduct", even if they have the same answer.

Comment: @cigien I don't know why you feel the need to spell this point out to me, complete with the emphatic "*not*" and the "Period.", given that I already explicitly agreed with the very point you are making in the comment that you are replying to.

Comment: @MarkAmery - Let's not descend into chaos here. The CoC is clear, and as the two answers pointed out, what happened at Discourse has no place here.

Comment: @MarkAmery I was just trying to be clear, not stern, but I do apologize if it came across that way. Reading some of your other comments, it appears (and I could be wrong), that you feel the user's alleged behavior on another site might be an indication of potentially problematic behavior on this site. If so, that's something that needs to be brought to moderators' attention, as it's not something the community can, or should, deal with. The OP's question here is simply "should a question on main be closed due to off-site interaction", and to that, the answer is an unqualified "no".

Comment: @NickCox - It wasn't closed because it was off-topic. He clearly stated in the comment why he voted to close it.

Comment: You are admitting to having been "verbally abusive". That's rare among those who are verbally abusive here, so a point to you there: most of the others have a Tr*mp-like conviction of the correctness of their position and their behaviour. As I read other comments here, stern advice to behave well is intended in your own best interests and is given noting that you are very new here (which is itself fine).

Comment: @NickCox - I told the truth rather than attempt to cover it up. I didn't go into detail because it wasn't necessary. I just used his words, he clearly stated in his comments, I was verbally abusive on Discourse.

Comment: Small nitpick. The score and the votes are not the same thing. (+37 / -14) is a score of 23, but there are 51 votes. (I know Stack uses "votes" in the user interface at places, which is feel is wrong.)

Comment: Your recent edit turns what is a general question that can be used to set policy, into a scrambled post rehashing the past. The point Cody made about not going over it stands and applies to you as well. There is no point daring anyone to answer or vote. Nobody is owed an answer to their question on SO, and if you burned that bridge, it's best to accept it gracefully instead of beating a dead horse.

Comment: I like your attitude about dropping it and moving on. Let's just *do that*, instead of continuing to *talk about* doing it. Thanks!

Comment: Anyone know why this account is deleted? Was this somehow related to the issue in this question?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

No, that's completely inappropriate. The question has now been re-opened, and irrelevant comments that do not relate to the subject of the question itself have been removed.

On Stack Overflow, the suitability of questions (and therefore the appropriateness of closure) is limited to assessments of the contents of the post. The user card behind it doesn't matter.

I don't know what went on over on that other forum, or whose fault it was, and I don't care to know. We're *not* going to rehash that here.

I just want *you* to know that Stack Overflow has a [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) and is far less tolerant of the types of shenanigans that may be allowed on other sites. I trust that you know this already; thanks for keeping it in mind.

Comment: I'd even go as far as calling it "abusive", considering 2 members of the same team close-voted that question. That's just bullying.

Comment: For completeness you might want to add that the appropriate action to take when something like this happens is to flag the closed post with a custom reason to notify a moderator of the situation.

Comment: Also some edits of the question here on meta are entirely inappropriate as well. If someone feels like they must tell their version of the story, they can post it as an answer, not by vandalizing the question. I really would expect 20k+ users with full user privileges to know better.

Comment: @Lundin - The funny part is, had he just answered my question on SO without bringing up what happened on Discourse, none of this would have happened. My question was straight to the point, and on topic.

Comment: @EmpressSvetlana let the strong consensus here not fool you. Repercussions on your question on SO due to abuse off-site are not OK. But by no means is it OK to be the troll that you were on the Julia discourse. Stefan has every right to consider you a _persona non grata_, and the last thing he should do is personally help you find answers to your questions. But yes, he should've just ignored your question here on SO.

Answer (score 13):

No, it's not. We moderate content, not users, here, and this is a classic case of moderating users.

In general, conduct outside of Stack Overflow is irrelevant. We don't enforce other communities' conduct standards and they don't enforce ours. It is patently inappropriate for them to come here to retaliate for behavior elsewhere.

Close votes and downvotes should never be used to punish the poster; they're solely for addressing low-quality content. Even suspension is [intended](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) to prevent the behavior in question; it's not a punishment, and it's certainly not to be used for addressing behavior that didn't even occur here. As the linked blog post says regarding suspension,

> We don’t hold grudges. The point of all this is to address the behavior. If the behavior improves, you are welcome back.

If someone believes that behavior that occurred **on Stack Overflow** needs to be addressed, they should flag for moderator intervention. If the behavior occurred elsewhere, there's nothing we can (or should) do about that.

Answer (score 9):

Stack Overflow as a community should focus on the content, not the user. If your posts here contain inflammatory or derogatory statements then sure, moderators or staff might take action against you, or at the very least your posts might get flagged or closed/deleted for valid reasons. But, if you exhibit decorum and refrain from such content in your posts and comments here, and follow the rules, then no adverse action should be taken against you.

Users are generally free to upvote and downvote as they see fit. However. users can get in trouble by serially voting everything to gain a badge, downvoting for reasons unrelated to the content of a question, raising too many unwarranted flags, or abusing privileges gained via reputation. They can even get in trouble over posting inflammatory comments in your direction because they recognized you from another site. Whenever you become the target of such behavior, it's best to raise a flag for a moderator to take a look. Make sure you choose an appropriate reason. If you don't have enough reputation to raise a flag, post here on Meta as you did for this.

If you feel you are targeted in a way that breaks the site's rules the best course of action is to flag (or post on Meta if you can't flag) and disengage with the offending user at once.

---

### Additional tips

Be mindful when encountering such users. If you engage the user you could wind up on the wrong side of the rules yourself if you are not careful, as arguments can quickly become heated and emotionally driven instead of based in rationality. In extreme cases it could turn into a flame war, which is a big no-no for this community. Don't stoke the fire, if you will.

This is very uncommon to be the case, but in the unlikely event you feel you are targeted or harassed by a *moderator* or other site staff, [this answer explains what to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/28869/180271).

You may also find it helpful to review Stack Overflow's [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), not only to ensure you understand the site's rules and guidelines, but also so you are aware when it is appropriate to flag or otherwise report another user for their behavior.

Since it was mentioned you may have two accounts, I want to clear up the misconception that it is disallowed to have multiple accounts on Stack Overflow. This is totally fine. What *is* disallowed is using one as a "sock-puppet" to promote your own content, such as voting for posts made by your other account(s). Stack Exchange has algorithms in place to identify such patterns between accounts interacting with each other. **You will** get caught if you do it, and activity between those accounts will be reversed at a minimum. Suspensions or account deletions are possible as well. So don't sock-puppet and you'll be fine.

Comment: It is also inappropriate to use multiple account to get around bans; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262060.  If you see that, flag the question as requiring moderator attention  ... and include the evidence of the behavior.